Authentication using Keycloak and spring cloud gateway
I am developing a Spring Boot application that utilizes Keycloak for authentication, and I am integrating it with Spring Cloud Gateway. However, I am facing challenges with token generation, specifically regarding the lifespan of the tokens.
Problem Statement:
Keycloak generates JSON Web Tokens (JWT) for authentication, but these tokens have a limited lifespan of up to 10 hours. My requirement is to generate a Personal Access Token (PAT) with a much longer lifespan, ideally around 6 months. Despite attempting to use Keycloak’s dedicated endpoints for token generation, I am consistently receiving JWT tokens instead of the desired long-lived PAT.
I tried using dedicated endpoints of keycloak to generate the token but i am getting JSON Web Tokens (JWT) for authentication, but these tokens have a limited lifespan of up to 10 hours. My requirement is to generate a Personal Access Token (PAT) with a much longer lifespan, ideally around 6 months.

You can't, and have to find another work around solution.

i found a read on https://blog.elest.io/adding-api-key-authentication-in-keycloak/#:~:text=Key%20Generation,event%20to%20generate%20the%20key.
